# Moodle - Show image only in frontpage

Tags: php, moodle

I am trying to display an image only on the front page of my Moodle.

Is there a way to detect where the user is, eg course page, profile page etc and use an if statment to display the picture only when the user is on the frontpage?

I am using a custom version of the Clean theme and I tried the code below.

When you are in a course it does not show the image, because the course with ID 1 is the frontpage, but it fails when you go to other pages, eg profile page.

```
<?php if ($PAGE->course->id == 1):?>
    <img src="<?php echo $OUTPUT->pix_url('header', 'theme'); ?>" class="img-responsive"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pagetype property in global $PAGE to check what page you are on

```
if (isset($PAGE) && (strpos($PAGE->pagetype, 'site-') === 0) {
    // I'm on the front page.
}
```

But you might be better off creating a front page layout. Edit theme/yourthemename/config.php and add (if its not there already)

```
$THEME->layouts = 
....
array(
    // The site home page.
    'frontpage' => array(
        'file' => 'frontpage.php',
        'regions' => array('side-pre', 'side-post'),
        'defaultregion' => 'side-pre',
        'options' => array('nonavbar' => true),
    ),
);
```

Then edit frontpage.php - if there isn't one then copy columns3.php to frontpage.php

Then you can have a custom frontpage :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Since Clean theme didn't have any layouts defined I didn't want to add any. If I add frontpage layout, I have to add layouts for all other layout types metioned here?            http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Themes_overview#The_different_layouts_as_of_21st_April_2013, or I can just defined the frontpage one and everything else will work normally?